# Rewrite custom url structure for custom template & post in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a web app using `WordPress` I have implemented a plugin for custom posting which product related all are ok but the problem is view URL.

I have created a template for product details view, source URL like this below

```
$category = Vehicle Accessories;

www.example.com/product-view/?category= $category
```

And get category name & view details based on the category name.

Generate below link:

```
www.example.com/product-view/?category=Vehicle%20Accessories
```

I need to below example

```
www.example.com/product-view/Vehicle%20Accessories
```

How can I implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can change the URL structure in Settings -> Permalinks.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen

Comment: Mmh, what plugin are you using?

Comment: I have created a plugin for new table